# How to Sort search results within a range?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working with ElasticSearch and trying to sort the results within a particular range.
That is my requirement is I want the search results having salary with a particular range and sort them.
So here is the query which I am trying:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/employee/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query": { "match_all": {} },
  "sort" : {
    salary : {
      "range" : {
        "gte": 20000,
        "lte": 30000
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

But i am getting the following exception when executing this:

```
"error" : "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all `shards failed; shardFailures {[eUQoAs5YTV-4zV0is80k-w][bank][0]: SearchParseException[[bank][0]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [\n{\n  \"query\": { \"match_all\": {} },\n  \"sort\" : {\n    balance : {\n      \"range\" : {\n        \"gte\": 20000,\n        \"lte\": 30000\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[sort option [range] not supported]; }`
```

I am not getting where i am making the mistakes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer using the filter as follows:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/employee/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "sort":{"salary": "asc"},
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": { "match_all": {} },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "salary": {
            "gte": 20000,
            "lte": 30000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, it says that `range` is not supported by the `sort` option.

So, you need to specify the range at your query, and then perform the sort:

```
GET index_name/type_name/_search
{
    "sort": {
      "salary": "asc"
    },
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "salary" : {
                "gte" : 20000,
                "lte" : 30000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use "salary": "asc" or "salary": "desc" for sorting in ascending or descending order. Hope it helps!

Comment: @KayV this answer should work, the error SearchPhaseExecutionException was due to you trying to place the range inside the sort block, in this answer the sort is properly moved so you shouldn't get the error anymore.. you should probably double check

Comment: I am running exactly the same query as stated in this answer, but getting the following error:>>>>>> "error" : "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures

Comment: Hmm so the error slightly changes, the part about the [sort option [range] not supported] disappeared. It must be something with the query itself. My ES version is 5.2 by the way.